# Rufus Scheduler blocks after how many threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rufus-scheduler

Writing a scheduler in rufus where the scheduled tasks will overlap. This is expected behavior, but was curious how rufus handles the overlap. Will it overlap up to n threads and then block from there? Or does it continue to overlap without a care of how many concurrent tasks run at a time.

Ideally I would like to take advantage of rufus concurrency and not have to manage my own pool of managed threads. Would like to block once I've reached the max pool count.

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

# Syncs one tenant in every call. Overlapping calls will allow for multiple
# syncs to occur until all threads expended, then blocks until a thread is available.
scheduler.every '30s', SingleTenantSyncHandler
```

**Edit**
Seeing from the [README](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#max_work_threads) that rufus does use thread pools in version 3.x. 
You can set the max thread count like:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:max_work_threads => 77)
```

Assuming this answers my question but still would like confirmation from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I confirm, https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#max_work_threads answers your question. Note that this thread pool is shared among all scheduled jobs in the rufus-scheduler instance.